# MySQL set LIMIT to 'child' table for JOIN operation

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql tables with many-to-many relationship

drivers

```
id           name         ...

1            'joe'
2            'bill'
3            'john'
...
```

buses

```
id           name         ...

1            'school'
2            'student'
3            'worker'
...
```

drivers_buses

```
id           driver_id_inner   bus_id_inner

1            1                 1
2            2                 1
3            2                 2
4            2                 3
5            1                 3
...
```

How select drivers with total count drivers less then 3. i.e if driver have 5 buses will be show only first 3 buses.

I try get it with some `JOIN` operation, but it throws drivers with count of the buses less then three.

```
        SELECT DRIVER.*, DRIVER_BUSES.bus_id_inner FROM drivers AS DRIVER

        INNER JOIN drivers_buses AS DRIVER_BUSES ON DRIVER.driver_id = DRIVER_BUSES.driver_id_inner

        INNER JOIN
          (
             SELECT drivers_buses.driver_id_inner
                    FROM drivers_buses GROUP BY drivers_buses.driver_id_inner HAVING COUNT(drivers_buses.driver_id_inner)<= 3
          )
        AS lessthenthree
        ON DRIVER.driver_id = lessthenthree.driver_id_inner
```

Comment: there is no `driver_id_inner` column in any of your three tables.  Please update your code or your table descriptions accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
select d.*, db.bus_id
from drivers d
join (
    select db1.driver_id, db1.bus_id
    from drivers_buses db1
    join drivers_buses db2 
        on  db1.driver_id = db2.driver_id
        and db2.id <= db1.id
    group by db1.driver_id, db1.bus_id
    having count(db2.id) <= 3
) db on db.driver_id = d.id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a4d26/3

You need to decide which three buses to show if there are more than three. In this solution i take the first three ordered by `drivers_buses.id`.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to worry about limiting the number of buses for a given driver on the Mysql query side. You can always hide unwanted data on the front-end perspect. You dont need to do such complex query.

Do something like this :

```
select count(*), D.name,B.name 
from drivers D, buses B, drivers_buses DB 
where GROUP BY D.name
```

Its good if you let the programming language handle such tasks, because you have quite flexibility in there.

Please update your question with front-end too on how you are showing data, whether php or any other language.